# ImageView outside parent (ListView item) programatically

Tags: android, listview, imageview, parent

I'm using a custom adapter for the ListView, and I want to put an  ImageView between list items (red item below). I've been struggling this issue for many hours unfortunately still found no answer.

[1 http://125.209.193.146/image/so_question.png](http://125.209.193.146/image/so_question.png)

What I have tried are

1) put an ImageView in the list item XML then set minus padding/margin
   -> hidden outside of it's parent list item

2) put an RelativeLayout outside the ListView and align exactly same with the ListView (as you know, layout_alignLeft/Right etc)
  -> problems occured when scroll the ListView (the ImageView doesn't follow while scrolling)

Any suggestion would be greatly appriciated!

[2 http://125.209.193.146/image/so_question2.png](http://125.209.193.146/image/so_question2.png)

Comment: do you want to add custom scrollbar for listview ?

Comment: no it's kind of a marker which represents progress for travelling. I finally found out the sollution which @Zach S. suggested

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas might be to look at updating your item's location in the view based on the scroll movement of the listview behind it, though this is not built in.

Another idea would be to just programatically build the page that way all items can be in the same layout/scrollview. Adding items to a scrollview programatically is not that difficult in Android and may work better then attempting to make items in a listview interact between each other as it is not designed for that.

Comment: Did you mean not to use the ListView/Adapter? Wouldn't be there any performance degradation without **Holder pattern** of Listview?

I'll try what you said if I will not able to find any better idea, thanks anyway!! (handling with scroll is not a good idea I think though)

Comment: The holder pattern (Reuse of views) is useful if you have really long lists. If it is going to be only of moderate length then the upfront build time is not overly important and the memory may be low enough. Its situational but you are trying to do something that is not built in so its a compromise of easy vs best.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with building layouts and views programatically, NOT WITH A LISTVIEW.

I was using the custom adapter and the listview but I found there's no way to put any view between the list items.

So, I build the parent(relative layout) and put all the views(ex-list items) in the parent as @Zach suggested then it finally worked.

cf) used the same layout xml with a layout inflator.

if someone wants more detail, please let me know